# Drag and Drop of ListBox items

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In my application I had two listboxes present in my same view. Is it possible to drag one listbox item and place the item on other listbox. I saw the functionality in iPhone.  Can I achieve the same in my application? If the answer is yes how I can implement the functionality in WP7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out my sample, I think this will solve your issue
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=a883d6dbbdbf62f5&resid=A883D6DBBDBF62F5!107

Comment: I tried the same in past but the result was failure and i thought this is only available in WPF and Silverlight . Any way thank u for reminding me that this functionality is available in WP7.

Comment: There are several example-projects on the specified SkyDrive-Folder, which one exactly is using the drag'n'drop?

Comment: Hello Rakesh, i didn't found any sample at the given link.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the tilt effect (on tiles) follows a similar concept. You can take the onmanipulationstarted event or the mouse left button down event, locate the point of touch and make the element follow the point of touch( one way would be to repeatedly change the x and y axes of the element), release the element at the mouseleftbuttonup event or manipulationcompleted event and run the logic on what to do with the element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this dragging item in listbox in an windows phone app called Pulse.

Basically, my thought is when touching or holding(depends on you decide how it triggers a drag action) happened in a listbox item, make its opacity to 0 or collapse its visibility, and render a picture for the item, then you can drag this picture (just looks like you drag the listboxitem) to wherever you want.

I don't know if you have seen the animation of ContextMenu in windows phone toolkit, but they just use this way to do the zoom effect