# Drag and Drop ListBoxItem between two Lists in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am designing an application which requires Drag&Drop functionality to transfer items from one list to another. Is there any way to drop item into another list, as i have seen applications to drag and drop items in the same list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop of Listbox Items IN wp7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925712/drag-and-drop-of-listbox-items-in-wp7)